# CP command prompt Windows 7 not recognized

Tags: windows, command, command-prompt

I am trying to run the command CP at the command prompt on Windows 7 but I'm getting:

```
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to install any software to run "cp" command?

If so what?

Comment: `cp` is unix, here is a [useful link](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/winforunix.html) that gives common translations between unix and windows,

Comment: chcp is a command to alter the code page.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is a unix/linux command. Download the cygwin package from cygwin.com

Comment: One can also use PowerShell to use cp in Windows

Comment: You don't need cygwin for this. You can use the Gnu-Win32 packages. Works without cygwin.

Answer (score 56):

**By default**, there's no `cp` in Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe). The equivalent cmd.exe command is `copy`. `cp` is a [Unix command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).

If you can use [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell) instead, which should come pre-installed in modern Windows systems, you can use `cp` and some other Unix commands directly in it.

If PowerShell isn't an alternative, you can use `cp` directly in Windows Command Prompt if you install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Moreover, Cygwin also includes the [`rsync` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html), which has many more features than `cp`, and might be preferable if you're not just copying a single file (e.g. for backup purposes).

Comment: There must be something as I've been able to run the command as "cp" on a windows server before

Comment: Oh, well... sorry then. I've never seen it. But maybe it was [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or something like that? I use Cygwin and really like it.

Comment: Btw, I just confirmed you can use `cp` from Windows prompt if you have Cygwin installed. And it also has `rsync`, which is a far more complete tool if you're not just copying one file around (e.g. backup purposes).

Comment: Cygwin has bunch of packages to select from when installing. Which should be selected?  https://i.imgur.com/Fvb6d3o.png

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to do run cp without cygwin and powershell and without admin rights.

Download the respective package ([CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)) from the [Gnu-Win32 package repository](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).

You need the [zipped binaries](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils-bin-zip.php) and the [zipped dependencies](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils-dep-zip.php).
Unpack, and copy bin from deps to bin from coreutils.

Now add the bin folder to the path environment variable (system or user, depending on if you're admin or not), and open a new console. Type cp, and you'll see standard cp command output.

Answer (score 0):

use cp of git , is good !
download here : https://git-scm.com/