# Git bash: 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: git-bash, cp, xgboost

In Git bash, when I use the cp command, it gives the error message:

'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue. I had to use copy in Windows instead of cp for it to work. See this link [CP Command Prompt Windows 7 not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734377/cp-command-prompt-windows-7-not-recognized).