# gsutil cp from cloud storage to remote windows machine

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, airflow, gsutil

I'm struggling to use gsutil cp command to copy some files from cloud storage to a Windows Server machine.

I cannot execute the command inside the Windows machine because this copy process is part of a dag in Airflow, and the Airflow machine should be able to run the cp command pointing to the Windows Server.

Any ideas on how to do this copy remotely?

Comment: Windows systems do not support the `cp` command. `gsutil` does not support remote file copies to Windows systems. You will need to use a different solution. I install Windows OpenSSH on my Windows systems so I can use `ssh/scp` to copy files.

Comment: @Giorge Caique, did you try installing OpenSSH as mentioned by John?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @John Hanley, Windows Systems do not support `cp` command. Here you can see a [similar question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734377/cp-command-prompt-windows-7-not-recognized#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20there%27s%20no%20cp,Unix%20commands%20directly%20in%20it.). `cp` is a [Linux command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).

Given the aforementioned, you will need to use a different solution. You migh want to [install Windows OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) on your Windows system and then use [ssh/scp](https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/netstorage/netstorage-user-guide/GUID-05522427-39B8-4299-A02A-B762CD888D78.html) to copy the files.